# swift:How to take screenshot of video when playing?

Tags: ios, swift, screenshot

I am working on a project where i play videos using custom controls for Avplayer.I want to allow the user to draw over a video and by taking screenshot of customized player using below code it works well in simulator whereas in physical device it returns black screen even after changing afterScreenUpdates:(true/false)

```
let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate!.window!!

//capture the entire window into an image
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(window.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
window.drawViewHierarchyInRect(window.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
let windowImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

//now position the image x/y away from the top-left corner to get the portion we want
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.frame.size)
windowImage.drawAtPoint(CGPoint(x: -imageView.frame.origin.x, y: -imageView.frame.origin.y))
let croppedImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//embed image in an imageView, supports transforms.
let resultImageView = UIImageView(image: croppedImage)
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(croppedImage, nil, nil, nil)
```

Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: false to the  afterScreenUpdates

Comment: @ john afordis  whats wrong in the code still it returns black screen?